# Convertendo um SQL do Sql Server para LINQ do C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Eu tenho um sql que é parecido com este:

```
SELECT coluna1, coluna2, coluna3
  FROM
  (
      SELECT coluna1, coluna2, coluna3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY coluna1, coluna3 desc) as row
       FROM tabela1
      WHERE coluna4 in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
  ) A
 WHERE
        A.ROW BETWEEN 1 AND 5
ORDER BY  A.ROW
```

E quero passar esta instrução para expressão LINQ do C#.

Obs.: Estou usando `ROW_NUMBER OVER(...)` para poder identificar o número da linha e poder fazer algo parecido com o que tem no ORACLE: `SELECT ... FROM ... limit 1,5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O teu `ROW_NUMBER()` seria algo equivalente ao `Top` pelo que entendi.
Para isso sua consulta poderia usar o `Take` que retorna um número especificado de elementos contíguos desde o início de uma seqüência.

Juntamente com o `Skip` que ignora um número especificado de elementos em uma seqüência e retorna os elementos restantes.

Tento assim uma paginação de seus dados.

```
var dados = (from t in tabela1
             where criterios....
            select new { Colunas....}).Skip(4).Take(5)
```

Comment: O `ROW_NUMBER()` que estou usando é parecido com o `TOP`, mas, eu quero por exemplo: `TOP 4, 5`. O que seria, a partir do 4ª registro retornar os próximos 5.

Comment: Usa o skip junto

Comment: Resumindo o que tu quer fazer é paginação.

Comment: Isto mesmo. Paginação.

Comment: Então tem que usar o skip e o take só não sei se a ordem ali ta certa, assim que chegar no serviço eu reedito a resposta

Comment: Editei minha resposta complementando com o uso do Skip.